# iOS Retina Display: Does "@2x" support jpeg as well as png?

Tags: iphone, ios, png, jpeg, retina-display

Can someone please confirm/deny whether the iPhone retina display supports the "@2x" filename scheme for jpeg as well as png?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

UIImage supports JPEGs and also automatically applies the @2 name modifier when running on a device with Retina display.

Answer (score 3):

yes it does. No difference on that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can, as UIImage itself supports the jpeg file format, as listed in a table at the top here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html